# Getting the text of a webelement through xpath

Tags: java, firefox, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the text of webelement through xpath. Attached are the html content of the page,
[image: First Page]

[image: Second Page where highlighted in Green is the text(Closed) that I needed]

I used the following code,

```
String v = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/div[contains(@class, 'ng-scope ngRow')]//div[contains(@class, 'ngCell ng-scope col7 colt7')//"
                + "div[contains(@class, 'ngCellText ng-scope ngCellElement col7 colt7')]")).getText();
```

This throws the error 'The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: ""]'.

When I downsized the search till

```
String v = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/div[contains(@class, 'ng-scope ngRow')]")).getText();
```

it works and I'm getting all the text in the particular row. However, when I extend it specific to a column as shown in the 1st code, I get error.

html snippet,

```
<div class="ng-scope ngRow even" ng-row="" ng-class="row.alternatingRowClass()" ng-click="row.toggleSelected($event)" ng-repeat="row in renderedRows" ng-style="rowStyle(row)" style="top: 0px; height: 30px;">
<div class="ngCell ng-scope pinned col0 colt0" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-dblclick="loadInstance(row.getProperty('incident_number'), 'ticket')" style="cursor: default;">
<div class="ngCell ng-scope col7 colt7" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" ng-dblclick="loadInstance(row.getProperty('incident_number'), 'ticket')" style="cursor: default;">
<div class="ng-isolate-scope" data-target="actions_menu" context-menu="">
<div ng-style="{ 'cursor': row.cursor }" style="cursor: default;">
<div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }"/>
<div ng-cell="">
<div class="ngCellText ng-scope ngCellElement col7 colt7" ng-class="col.colIndex()" tabindex="0">
<span class="ng-binding" ng-cell-text="">Closed</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your second XPath query the farthest you can get into the DOM before experiencing errors?  Would it be possible for you to post (as code) the relevant pieces of your markup so we can test your queries?

Comment: No, the second query is the one that works. If I go deep to the next level as mentioned in the 1st query, it fails.

Comment: Images with code are unreadable. Please replace them with actual text, indented by four spaces. Then, it is automatically rendered as HTML. _But_: Identify the _relevant_ snippet of HTML, do not bombard us with lots of markup.

Comment: @MathiasMüller, added HTML code for better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it out with following results: in the pasted HTML 3 closing `</div>` are missing.
With a minimal adjustment of your XPath, I get following result:

```
<div class="ngCellText ng-scope ngCellElement col7 colt7" 
 ng-class="col.colIndex()"  tabindex="0">
 <span class="ng-binding" ng-cell-text="">Closed</span>
</div>
```

You're just missing a ] in the first XPath, then it should work:

```
"//div[1]/div[contains(@class, 'ng-scope ngRow')]
//div[contains(@class, 'ngCell ng-scope  col7 colt7')//"
+ "div[contains(@class, 'ngCellText ng-scope ngCellElement col7 colt7')]")) ..
```

in the 2nd line the closing ] is missing, it should be:

```
"//div[1]/div[contains(@class, 'ng-scope ngRow')]
//div[contains(@class, 'ngCell ng-scope  col7 colt7')]//"
```

As I just used an XPath-Tester for checking and don't have the same setting you're working on, you should just give it a try. Hope that helps.